# Backup Code Snippets for Xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode, code-snippets, xcode4.6

I've been searching for backing up user code snippet for Xcode, and i got this below which is only for system snippets!

> For Xcode's self contained app. This is the exact file path of the
>   default snippets:
>   "/Applications/Xcode4.3.3.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECodeSnippetLibrary.ideplugin/C‌​ontents/Resources/SystemCodeSnippets.codesnippets

Where is the user code snippet for Xcode 4.6?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your user code snippets can be found in

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets/
```

Where the ~/Library is the current users home directory.

Comment: Thank you Gavin for the answer. After been trying to find out how to get the Library folder for a while and then I have found it!
 Just a simple way,  to open the user-Library-folder without Terminal you just hold alt & than choose Library in the Go-dropdown from the Findermenu!

Comment: @webmastx Glad I could help. You can also just type the above into the `Go to Folder...` and it will take you directly to the CodeSnippets.